# Scrape an aspx site using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like **scrape** this page:

https://bakalar.vos-sosmost.cz:8080/rozvrh.aspx

I want to fill the form, with this data:

`třída=1.E`

Is there some easy way to fill the form and **scrape** site with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: You must use ```post``` method of ```requests``` module

Comment: When you are dealing with Core Javascript featured website then Selenium would be the best choice. because data will be loaded using js after form fillup.

Comment: FYI it’ __scrape__ not scrap

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `beautifulsoup` will not help you to fill the form data

`$('#combotrida_I').value = "1.E"`

This is what you are supposed to do to fill the data but in this case, to automate the process you should look at using selenium to fill the data and you could use `beautifulsoup` to find out the elements class name which you want to fill the data to.

Here is a website that could help you get started -> https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html